# azure push notification on table row update

Tags: azure, row, push, azure-notificationhub

I have a table in azure, MyTableoFruitPrices, it contains many data.
This table is (clearly) of fruit prices and each user can subscribe to only one (and only one) fruit price change notification.

How does one achieve this in azure ?

Buzz

Answer (score 0):

Buzz,

There may be a more graceful approach, but I would take the approach of creating a trigger FOR INSERT and UPDATE that write the INSERTED table information (the updated fruit price) into a table. This would be a table you create that is an "Outbox" of a sort, so essentially the trigger would simply insert into this table from the INSERTED table.

Next, create an Azure Worker Role that monitors this OUTBOX table, ad make calls to PN accordingly. The frequency of the check can be tweaked so that it is nearly real-time, depending on your needs. You can even consider creating a Service Bus that the Worker Role writes to, and create competing consumers that send the PN using tags, filters, etc.